# How to build an escrow contract that accepts ERC20 tokens like usdt, usdc etc not only ether

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, erc-20, escrow

I am building an escrow smart contract, i would like the escrow to be able to receive ERC20 tokens preferably stable coins like USDT OR USDC and not ether.

Is there a way to implement this to my contract please ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to implement the ability to receive ERC20 tokens in an escrow contract. Here is an example of how this could be done:

Import the ERC20 contract:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v3.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
```

Define the ERC20 token you want to receive in the contract

```
contract Escrow {
    SafeERC20 public token;

    constructor(SafeERC20 _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }
}
```

Add a function to the contract to allow the user to deposit ERC20 tokens:

```
function deposit(uint256 _amount) public {
    // Transfer the tokens from the user's account to the contract
    require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount), "Transfer failed");

    // Store the deposited tokens in a mapping
    // You can use a struct or any other data structure to store the deposited tokens
    depositedTokens[msg.sender] += _amount;
}
```

Add a function to the contract to allow the user to withdraw the deposited tokens:

```
function withdraw(uint256 _amount) public {
    // Check if the user has enough deposited tokens
    require(depositedTokens[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Not enough deposited tokens");

    // Transfer the tokens from the contract to the user's account
    require(token.transfer(msg.sender, _amount), "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to implement a similar function. Try this. I am not sure if it'll work but give it a try.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract ABC{
    
    function enter() public payable {
    
    IERC20 token = IERC20(`0x123`); // Insert the token contract address instead of `0x123`
    require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), .01 ether));
}


}
```

Comment: Hello, how exactly do i import this into the code? let's say i want to use only usdc erc20

Comment: just replace '0x123' with the USDC contract address.